# VS 2010 Solution depending on another Solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, build-process, projects-and-solutions

I Have 2 solutions (lets say Master Framework M and Slave Project S).
M is used by many solutions of the S kind.
In my build process I build all the DLL from M and THEN use them in S.
While working I would like a faster cycle  where I can easily modify M and immediately using in S.

The problems as you may know are all related to the way you reference libraries or projects in a csproj file.

If you want to link a DLL you have to do something like this

```
<Reference>
  <HintPath>..\lib\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\M.Example.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

If you want to link a Project (even from another solution) you have to do it this way

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\path to project in other solution\M.Example.csproj">
  <Project>{2009D1C4-E18F-6CF8-8AA4-B53A1B2F1009}</Project>
  <Name>M.Example</Name>
</ProjectReference>
```

And this is written directly in the C# project (csproj) file! So you can't use a project or a DLL for different purposes in a same file

I don't want to maintain 2 csproj files one referencing all the DLL for the build process and the other one with the references to the projects for develop & CI purposes.

The two main ideas I had are:
1) Leave 2 distinct solutions and work in M then build and work in S referencing only the DLL and using a custom input project (only in developement) which copies the DLL produced in M in the lib directory of S so S can use them without looking outside the S root or referencing other projects.

2) Use a Condition like this

```
<Reference Condition='$(BUILDING)!=""'>
  <HintPath>..\lib\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\M.Example.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>

<ProjectReference Condition='$(BUILDING)==""' Include="..\path to project in other solution\M.Example.csproj">
  <Project>{2009D1C4-E18F-6CF8-8AA4-B53A1B2F1009}</Project>
  <Name>M.Example</Name>
</ProjectReference>
```

Where BUILDING is defined only in the official build process.

I would like to make this a lot easier and maybe smarter

Comment: how many projects is in M solution?

Comment: What exactly does it mean for a solution to depend on a solution? Usually, some projects in solution S depend on some projects in solution M. Is that what you mean? If so, you could simply add those projects to *both* solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You should think about the design. In the first moment you will save time with the compile process but later you will spend more time in fixing your Master to fit all the Slaves.

Usually you want to generate the Master (M) every time you change it. Imagine you Change M so that it has a new feature for S1 and everything works fine. Some time later you try to compile S2 an get an exception based on the changes to M that you made for S1.

To avoid that issue you usually use version numbers, to make sure that p.e. S1 works with Version 1.0 of M and S2 works with version 1.1 of M. Of course you want your Master project to be always compatible to all versions but that can be hard to maintain and you will be happy if a change brakes at most one Slave project a time.

With postbuild events you can apply some code that copy your output to other projects. I used that once but inside one project. With multiple solutions you cant be sure, that the path will fit on other machines.

**UPDATE:**
In addition I found this Article that explains solution management very well:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817674.aspx

Comment: Yes this is certainly the correct approach we want to use when all is consolidated, but we are in the start-up phase of the projects (both M and S) so a lot of changes and new features in M happen because of S needs. We already have a full version number policy but in this phase we actually need a rapid round trip from M to S and vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

I would stand for a first sollution:

In your M solution use *PostBuild events* to copy latest build binaries in some location. And S projects consume those binaries by referencing them like a DLLs in project.

In this way one time you rebuild M, all S projects will refer to the latest version of M.